# How to do Joins with Knex and React

Tags: reactjs, database, join, knex.js

I have created a https://github.com/RobertWSON/Personal-ship-project/tree/classicruiseships-only-with-joins branch to work out how to use joins with tables for my cruise ship website.

**I have not got the joins working yet for each ship, as can be seen with cruise ship specs shown below
So, I need some help to figure out how to get this working.**

I have an [evo1 table](https://github.com/RobertWSON/Personal-ship-project/blob/classicruiseships-only-with-joins/migrations/20200619215514_evo1.js#L61) that has two joins to cruise_convert and name_changes_pt1 tables.
Also [evo2 table](https://github.com/RobertWSON/Personal-ship-project/blob/classicruiseships-only-with-joins/migrations/20201002142621_evo2.js#L57) has three joins to classic_cruising, classic_lengthened and name_changes_pt2 tables.

I also have [seeds](https://github.com/RobertWSON/Personal-ship-project/tree/classicruiseships-only-with-joins/seeds) related to this as well.

**I have done joins for each of the tables in a database file called [dbclassic.js](https://github.com/RobertWSON/Personal-ship-project/blob/classicruiseships-only-with-joins/server/db/dbclassic.js#L19)**

This is the code I have used for getting data from each of the tables (evo1 or evo2) and you can see the joins I have added

```
  const environment = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'
    const config = require('../../knexfile')[environment]
    const db = require('knex')(config)
    
    
    function getClassic(classic_ship_name, testConn)    {
    
        const conn = testConn || db 
        console.log('server/db/dbclassic.js getClassic called!')   
        
        // Initialize evo1 table as a starting point for displaying data
        let evo1
    
        // Line below connects to Evo1 Table for Evolution Part 1 
        return conn('Evo1')
    
            // Use a Join here to connect evo1 table with other tables
            .join('cruise_convert', 'cruise_convert.id', 'evo1.cruise_convert_id')
            .join('name_changes_pt1', 'name_changes_pt1.id', 'evo1.name_changes_pt1_id')
            
            .where('classic_ship_name', classic_ship_name)
        
            //Line below picks out Classic Ship Names in alphabetical order by id
            .orderBy('id')
        
            // .first() method returns only the first result, which is an object not an Array.
            .first()
             
            //This picks up the information for a Classic Ship page eg Titanic in Evolution Part 1
            .then((EvoOneResults) => {
                console.log('dbclassic.js - GOT CLASSIC SHIP:', EvoOneResults)
            evo1 = EvoOneResults
       
        // Line below connects to Evo2 Table for Evolution Part 2         
        return conn('Evo2')
        
            // Use a Join here to connect evo2 table with other tables
            .join('classic_cruising', 'classic_cruising.id', 'evo2.classic_cruising_id')
            .join('classic_lengthened', 'classic_lengthened.id', 'evo2.classic_lengthened_id')
            .join('name_changes_pt2', 'name_changes_pt2.id', 'evo2.name_changes_pt2_id')
    
            .where('classic_ship_name', classic_ship_name)
            .orderBy('id') 
            .first()
        })
        // This picks up the information for a Classic Ship page eg Fairstar in Evolution Part 2
            .then((EvoTwoResults) => {
            console.log('dbclassic.js - GOT CLASSIC SHIP:', EvoTwoResults)
        
        // This displays information for a Classic Ship, taken from either evo1 or evo2 seeds     
        return  {        
            evo1,
            evo2: EvoTwoResults
        }           
        })
    
    }
    
    module.exports = {
        getClassic
    }
```

**Now this Evolution part of the website works like this:**
6 Classic ships are shown on either Evolution Part 1 or Part 2 pages.    When a user click on a ship image, it takes you to the       classic_ship_name page.
This is where the ship specs are shown on       right side of the page.

**Initial Ship Specs shown at the top right side of the page have data , but below it as a Cruise Ship and after Lengthening do not have any data, so this is where my join is not working**

I need help to understand why the data is not coming through. If anyone has any suggestions that may help, that will be much appreciated.

[image: Classic Ships - Click Image]

[image: Ship Specs Initial Data Shows]

[image: No Cruise Ship Data]
[image: No Lengthened Details]